# MassTransit RabbitMQ AspNetCore not starting the bus and registering receive endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, masstransit

I've been battling with this for hours now but I can't seem to get it to work despite seemingly copying the documentation.

I'm using the new MassTransit AspNetCore package to register my bus and a consumer but it doesn't seem to be starting the bus! If I add a break point by the code the registers the receive endpoint it never gets hit (but the AddBus part does) and the exchange/queue doesn't get created.

It's worth noting that this is just a Web API that runs in IIS and that there are also normal rest endpoints too (I don't know if that would matter or not).

My code is as follows:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<SelectAllAccessibleConsumer>();

    x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
    {
        var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(rabbitMqMessageBus.Host), rabbitMqMessageBus.Username,
            hostConfigurator =>
            {
                hostConfigurator.Username(rabbitMqMessageBus.Username);
                hostConfigurator.Password(rabbitMqMessageBus.Password);

                if (rabbitMqMessageBus.UseSsl)
                {
                    hostConfigurator.UseSsl(s => { s.Protocol = SslProtocols.Tls12; });
                }
            });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "queue-name", ep =>
        {
            ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
            ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));
            ep.ConfigureConsumer<SelectAllAccessibleConsumer>(provider);
        });
    }));
});
```

I can't help but feel like I'm missing something immensely obvious but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to actually start the bus, which in your scenario should be done using a hosted service. You can see the sample here:

https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ConsoleService/blob/master/SampleService/MassTransitConsoleHostedService.cs

```
public class MassTransitConsoleHostedService :
    IHostedService
{
    readonly IBusControl _bus;

    public MassTransitConsoleHostedService(IBusControl bus, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _bus = bus;

        if (loggerFactory != null && MassTransit.Logging.Logger.Current.GetType() == typeof(TraceLogger))
            MassTransit.ExtensionsLoggingIntegration.ExtensionsLogger.Use(loggerFactory);
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _bus.StartAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _bus.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And then, add to your configuration:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MassTransitConsoleHostedService>();
```

Comment: Thanks Chris I knew it was going to be something like that but couldn't find it in the docs!

Comment: It is weird that they mention in the documentation that the package includes this startup feature. http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/configuration.html#masstransit-and-aspnet-core: 

```The package includes the following features:
Hosted service to start and stop the bus following the application lifecycle```

Comment: Also for ASP.NET Core there seems to be incomplete documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791857/asp-net-core-service-not-creating-rabbitmq-queue/56794728#56794728

Answer (score 6):

Actually the IServiceHost registration is included in the library though it is not mentioned in the documentation.
Need to use the extension:

```
services.AddMassTransitHostedService()
```