# ASP.NET Core service not creating RabbitMQ queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq, masstransit

Being a new user of MassTransit and RabbitMQ I'm currently trying to make my ASP.NET core service to work with MassTransit.

Taking this [documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/configuration.html#masstransit-and-aspnet-core) section to configure MassTransit and ASP.NET Core I'm unable to get it working.

Currently (part of) the Startup.cs looks like

```
 services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<MailConsumer>();
                x.AddConsumer<MailFailedConsumer>();

                x.AddBus(provider => ConfigureBus(provider, rabbitMqConfigurations));
            });


private IBusControl ConfigureBus(
                            IServiceProvider provider,
                            RabbitMqConfigSection rabbitMqConfigurations) => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(
                            cfg =>
                            {
                                var host = cfg.Host(
                                    rabbitMqConfigurations.Host,
                                    "/",
                                    hst =>
                                    {
                                        hst.Username(rabbitMqConfigurations.Username);
                                        hst.Password(rabbitMqConfigurations.Password);
                                    });

                                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"{typeof(MailSent).Namespace}.{typeof(MailSent).Name}", endpoint =>
                                {
                                    endpoint.Consumer<MailConsumer>(provider);
                                });

                                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, $"{typeof(MailSentFailed).Namespace}.{typeof(MailSentFailed).Name}", endpoint =>
                                {
                                    endpoint.Consumer<MailFailedConsumer>(provider);
                                });
                            });
```

The exchange is created automatically in RabbitMQ on startup, but no queue is bind to the exchange which I would expect.

After invoking my API endpoint I can see activity on the exchange, but of course the consumers doing nothing as there is no queue.

What (obvious) part am I missing?

Comment: Yeah, the MT hosted service doesn't get registered. Can you put your repo on GitHub? I can have a quick look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. It worked as described in the docs at the moment the docs were written. There are several `AddMassTransit` extensions for the `IServiceCollection` interface, which is confusing.

`AddMassTransit` overload, which accepts the bus instance works as described.

`AddMassTransit` overload, which accepts the `Action<IServiceCollectionConfigurator>` only does necessary registrations.

You need to add one line:

```
services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

and your code will work.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot :-) Although now I'm getting `MassTransit bus is not ready` in the health checks. Queues and exchanges are created though!

Comment: Fixed the `MassTransit bus is not ready` by adding : `cfg.UseHealthCheck(provider);`

Comment: Yeah, I believe that was in the docs :) Still need to clarify this, thanks for pointing it out :)